# $(Fx)(t) = f(t)x(t)$ is unitary iff $|f(t)| = 1$ almost everywhere

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, inner-products

The problem comes from Naylor's Linear Operator Theory Section 5.19 Problem 4

> Let $I = [a, b]$ be a bounded interval and define $F : L_2(I) → L_2(I)$
>   by $(F x)(t) = f(t)x(t)$, where $f ∈ L_∞(I)$. Show that $F$ is a unitary mapping if and only if $|f(t)| = 1$ almost
>   everywhere.

I've already shown $F$ is unitary given $|f(t)| = 1$ a.e.. It's the forward direction that is giving me trouble. I know $\langle Fx,Fy\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$ implies
$\int_I f(t)^2x(t)y(t)dt= \int_I x(t)y(t)dt.$

I feel like I'm missing something super simple. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you got $\int_I (f(t)^2-1)x(t)y(t)dt = 0$ for each $x,y \in L_2(I)$. So, you just want the general result saying $\int_I g(t)h(t)dt = 0$ for all $h \in L_1(I)$ implies $g(t) = 0$ almost everywhere. I'm sure you can find this general result somewhere on this website, but the quickest way to prove it is to just let $h = 1_{g > 0}$ or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x=y=I_E$ where $E$ is any measurable set in $[a,b]$. You get $\int_E \phi (t)dt=0$ where $\phi (t)=1-|f(t)|^{2}$. This implies $\phi=0$ a.e.: take $E=\{x: \phi (t) >0\}$  to see that $\phi (t) \leq 0$ a.e. and then take $E=\{x: \phi (t) <0\}$  to see that $\phi (t) \geq 0$ a.e.